# How to send a form via postman/insomnia http client on a Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, insomnia

I have a Controller with the following code

```
class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);

    }
}
```

I remember about `csrf` protection and I've found my `csrf` token on my frontend. So, I've added it on the fields in http client insomnia. But as the result I've the following

[image]

Content-Type is `multipart/form-data`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has middleware group called web that protects your routes. it's inside the `web.php` file.
you can see routes middleware in the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

```php
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

web middleware group add lots of middleware to your project such as `VerifyCsrfToken`

you could see list of them in `app/Http/Kernel.php'

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
         \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

as you may know, Laravel has another middleware and route folder called api, that doesn't have any CSRF protection.
you can declare your route that doesn't need CSRF protection (I mean API of your application) to `route/api.php`

By declaring that kind of routes in `route/api.php` file you can easily make the request with Postman/Insomnia like app.

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to understand why I can't send form via http client? I've added the token on in the set of fields. So what difference between real form and my emulation?

Comment: how do you calculate _token field?

Comment: Easy) On the frontend `<h1>{{ csrf_token() }}</h1>` and CTRL + F5

Comment: you have 2 options: 1) add this route to except array in `app/http/middleware/VerifyCsrfToken` 2) add a cookie to your request because Laravel check both cookie and _token field

Comment: Ok, second option looks like interesting! I will try it.